# Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: ruby, libssl

I'm encountering the following error when requiring the `curb` Ruby gem:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

$ gem install curb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed curb-0.8.6
1 gem installed

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'curb'
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/curb-0.8.6/curb_core.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/curb-0.8.6/curb_core.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/curb-0.8.6/curb_core.bundle
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/curb-0.8.6/lib/curb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/scott/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944770/uwsgi-can-not-load-libssl-1-0-0-dylib

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL can't load library with gem rubygems or brew or bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946856/openssl-cant-load-library-with-gem-rubygems-or-brew-or-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it looks like you are using rbenv. I had the same problem and did reinstall the same version of ruby using rbenv.

That fixed the problem. Source: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946993/700317)